# How to pass textbox value to Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to pass a textbox value in asp.net to the javascript variable videoID and save it to the database.

**Here is my code**

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPI() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '350',
width: '600',
videoId: 'ASO_zypdnsQ',
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

if you use **asp:TextBox** for videi id than try this

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPI() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '350',
width: '600',
videoId: document.getElementsById('<% ClientID.VideoId %>').value,
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}
</script>
```

or

if you use simple **html textbox** than try this

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPI() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '350',
width: '600',
videoId: document.getElementsByid("your textbox's ID").value,
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follows if it's you aspx page

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPI() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '350',
width: '600',
videoId: '<% AspCode.VideoId %>',
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}
</script>
```

If it's not Aspx page, you can define javascript variable in js file

`var videoId = '<% AspCode.VideoId %>'`;

And than take video id from the variable.